# Form1.vb [Design] is empty

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms

so I have this project that I use for work, and I went in to add some features.
It's basically a customized calculator.

While I was working, I clicked on my Form1.vb [Design] to look at my form. (Which is my main form)
I got a Windows Forms Designer error page. It had a problem with a particular line of code, even though the app ran and functioned correctly. I've come across this before a few times. I always clicked "Ignore and continue" and it was fine. This time my main form (Form1) was completely blank as if it was a new form. all of the code for my buttons/text boxes, etc... is still there.

is there a way to get it back? is it just hidden somewhere?
If anyone knows what's going on, I would really appreciate any help you could offer.

I attached a screenshot of my last working version of the app. Before the additions I was trying to implement.

[image: Form1]

I'm not super knowledgeable with coding, but I get by with some intermediate projects.
So I apologize if I don't know a lot of the terminology.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using source-control?

Comment: What exactly was the problem stated in the design time error? You said you always ignored but did you ever read that? Pretty sure your answer is in that error prone line.

Comment: It said it couldn't read a particular line, or something of that nature. it was just a property that I gave to a label.

Comment: Not sure what was wrong with it even still. But now I can't find that error prone line. I think there's a whole chunk of my code missing but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you clarify what is in the `FormName.Designer.vb` file? And does it show any errors? When you say that… _“all of the code for my buttons/text boxes, etc... is still there.”_ … ? … Where is there?... The code for all the buttons etc. is IN the `FormName.Designer.vb` file? Or is this code somewhere else?

Comment: All of my code where I've assigned what the buttons do, etc... is in Form1.Designer.vb There are no errors

Comment: I put everything in there... Most of the functionality is comprised of If Then statements. displaying different numbers on the labels and text boxes based on the input. Not sure if that helps at all.

Comment: You last comment is raising an eyebrow… _”I put everything in there”_ … ? … What code are you “manually” adding to the `Form1.Designer.vb` file? You state that… _”Most of the functionality is comprised of If Then statements. displaying different numbers on the labels and text boxes based on the input.”_ … ? … based on what input? What “input” are you describing? When the form is instantiated, do you have this “input”? If not, when do you get this “input”?

Comment: If you've lost all your source code because you were wrongly putting it in the `.designer.vb` file _and_ you aren't using source-control, you can probably still recover most of your project by disassembling any earlier builds (`.exe`/`.dll` files) you have lying around, but it won't be pretty.

Comment: When first opening the app, everything is blank like in the pic above. For example, in the combo box labeled “material” I have listed the names of several materials that we use in our shop. (I work at a printing company) these are assigned prices, which I have defined on another form. It multiplies the price of that material by whatever number I enter in the “square footage” text box. And displays the calculation in the text box on the right labeled “material. It does something similar for the other boxes and displays the grand total in the green box.

Comment: All of the code that makes it work I put in Form1.designer.vb

Comment: The code that I’ve written is all still there, in designer.vb. The loops, instructions etc… and it runs without error like nothing is wrong, but my main form is now blank. Where should I be writing all that? I always double clicked the thing I wanted to give instructions to and it would open “private sub nameofthing_click” in designer.vb and I would tell it what to do there. Is that not correct?

Comment: Thanks to everyone taking the time to help me by the way, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hmm… are you 100% sure about… _”I always double clicked the thing I wanted to give instructions to and it would open “private sub nameofthing_click” in designer.vb”_ … ? … when I do this to add the click event... it opens the `Form1.vb` file NOT the `Form1.Desgner.vb` file.

Comment: Interesting... It does for sure open in 'Form1.designer.vb' in this project. for all buttons. but I opened another completely unrelated project, and that one opened in Form1.vb... not sure how that happened? I never really looked at those labels before.

Comment: If you haven't already done so, make a copy of the solution folder (ie: save to an external USB drive).

Comment: You'll find it easier to open the desired files if you use Solution Explorer. On VS menu, click `View`. Then select `Solution Explorer`. In Solution Explorer, right-click your form (ex: Form1.vb) and select `View Code` or `View Designer`.  Click the arrow next to "Form1.vb" to expand it. Now click the arrow next to "Form1" to expand it. Double-click "Dispose" which will open "Form1.Designer.vb" - which is where the controls that you have on the form are listed.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. What I ended up doing was re-creating my main UI on a new form, naming all of the elements the same names as I had them before, and copy pasting my code from `oldform.designer.vb` to `newform.vb` and that got me back to where I was before.